# Vector resultant

Tags: javascript, html, vector, input, nan

I'm trying to make a resultant of 3 vectors. But when I put a number, return NaN instead.Can someone explain?

```
var vectoro = document.getElementById("f1");
var vectortw = document.getElementById("f2");
var vectorth = document.getElementById("f3");
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
var d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
var hasil = document.getElementById("hasil");

function prosessatu(){
let f1 = vectoro * Math.cos(d1.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let f2 = vectortw * Math.cos(d2.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let f3 = vectorth * Math.cos(d3.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let fsino = vectoro * Math.sin(d1.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let fsintw = vectortw * Math.sin(d2.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let fsinth = vectorth * Math.sin(d3.value * Math.PI / 180).toFixed(2);
let sigmafx = Math.pow((f1 + f2 + f3), 2);
let sigmafy = Math.pow((fsino + fsintw + fsinth), 2);
hasil.value = Math.sqrt((sigmafx + sigmafy))
}
vectoro.oninput = prosessatu;
d1.oninput = prosessatu;

vectortw.oninput = prosessatu;
d2.oninput = prosessatu;

vectorth.oninput = prosessatu;
d3.oninput = prosessatu;
```

I'm using `<input type = "numbers">`

Answer (score 0):

The type of your input should be `number`, not `numbers`

[See documentation for number input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number)

However my understanding is that type attribute is only used by browser to validate the field. When retrieving its value using javascript, you will get a String.

So you need to parse it, e.g

```
var d1 = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById("d1"));
```